# ggplot percentage within grouping

Tags: r, ggplot2

How would I be able to plot the grouped percentages (not the counts) of a dataset in ggplot? For example this plot

```
library(survival)
    ggplot(data=kidney, aes(disease))+
      geom_bar(aes(fill=as.factor(sex)), position="dodge")
```

How could I plot the `sex` as a percentage of the disease group that they are in such that each disease group should add up to 100%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the percentage first and then plot the data.

```
library(survival)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

kidney %>%
  count(disease, sex = factor(sex))  %>%
  group_by(disease) %>%
  mutate(n = prop.table(n) * 100) %>%
  ggplot(aes(disease, n, fill = sex)) + geom_col(position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but should that not also work w/i `ggplot` somehow? I get it work using `after_stat()` for percentage per sex but not per disease: `ggplot(kidney) + geom_bar(aes(x = disease, y = after_stat(prop), group = factor(sex), fill = factor(sex)), position = "dodge")`

Comment: Yes, that might work with only `ggplot` as well. I get very confused though hence I prefer to keep data manipulation step separate from plotting step.

Comment: Fair enough, I was just wondering how it could work, just using `ggplot2`. According to the [The Grammar of Graphics](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9780387245447) on which `ggplot2` is built, it would be just calling a appropriate statistics before plotting.